# How to get data from other tables with id's

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having troubles with a query that is driving me nuts.

I have a table with some fields that are id's from other tables in my database.
What I'd like to do is to get an output of each record with the corrispondent data for each id.

I'll try to make an example:

Table with ID's:

username | rank | nationality | city
usr_1            1         1234        123

And tables for each colum where to one of these id's there's the actual name.

I'd like to replace the id's with the actual names, since the output on the php page is going to be "unreadable" if I keep the numbers on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pretty basic query...inner join to the table to translate the ID and repeat for each column.  "I'm having troubles with a query that is driving me nuts."  post up what you have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you get this information by joins with the other tables:

```
SELECT
    u.username,
    u.rank
    n.nationality,
    c.city
FROM
    your_table u
INNER JOIN
    nations n
ON
    u.nationality = n.id
INNER JOIN
    cities c
ON
    u.city = c.id
```

or so. I don't know the names of your tables and columns, but the principle should be clear.

Answer (score -1):

You could do nested queries. The table you put in your post is called *userdetails* here by me.

Something like this:

```
SELECT   
 (SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = u.username),   
 (SELECT rank_name FROM ranks WHERE id = u.rank),   
 (SELECT nationality_name FROM nationalities WHERE id = u.nationality),   
 (SELECT city_name FROM cities WHERE id = u.city) 
FROM userdetails u
```